# n-dash shows up as â€“

Tags: reactjs, utf-8, utf-16, utf

I am trying to include the n-dash character as part of a string I'm rendering in my ReactJS web app. I'm including the n-dash encoding (\u2013) in a string and I have UTF-16 as the specified encoding in a meta tag. But the character keeps showing up as 'â€“' when deployed. What am I doing wrong?

The n-dash character is returned as part of a string assembled in a javascript function:

```
export const getEventTimeRange = (startTime, endTime, middle ='\u2013') => { 
    const rioStartTime = moment(startTime);
    const rioEndTime = moment(endTime);

    if (rioEndTime - rioStartTime > 82800000) return 'All Day';

    const formattedRioStart = rioStartTime.format('h:mm A');    

    if (rioEndTime - rioStartTime === 0) return formattedRioStart;

    const formattedRioEnd = rioEndTime.format('h:mm A');

    return `${formattedRioStart} ${middle} ${formattedRioEnd}`;
};
```

Comment: Please provide more information. Is the n-dash character in an HTML and Javascript file? Is the n-dash character specified in some sort of symbolic notation (such as "\u2013") or as a regular unicode character? Which file specifies UTF-16 as the encoding? The HTML or Javascript file? Are you really using UTF-16 for transmitting HTML and Javascript (very unusual)? Have you stored your HTML or Javascript file in UTF-16 on the server side as well?

Comment: Additionally show the headers of the transmitted HTML and Javascript file (Chrome developer tools can display it). And add code to your question if you expect an answer.